# Spatial relationships that do not match

Tags: arcobjects, c#

All,
I have 2 layers as shown below
[image]

What I want to do is go through each feature (in pink) and do a spatial filter against the green layer.
My current code is

```
        inMemFeatCur = inMemFeatClass.Search(null, true);
        inMemFeature = inMemFeatCur.NextFeature();
        while (inMemFeature != null)
        {
            //set the spatial filter
            ISpatialFilter spaFil = new SpatialFilterClass();
            spaFil.Geometry = inMemFeature.Shape;
            spaFil.GeometryField = validationLayer.ShapeFieldName;
            spaFil.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
            spaFil.SpatialRelDescription = "";

            //query the results from the spatial filter

            IFeatureCursor geomCursor = inMemFeatClass.Search(spaFil, true);
```

The problem is the when I go through the geomCursor, it will not find the polygon that is completely outside.

The check i want to do is each polygon (pink) completely within (common boundaries allowed) the green layer. If it is not, a warning will to appear.

I know that IRelationalOperator returns a bool, but i have to go through each green feature which I don't want to do, as I'll be looping many times for each pink feature.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the IFeatureSelection interface to obtain the selection set from an **existing** selection (so all pink polygons intersecting green polygons) and invert it.

Below is some VBA code to show you how to use ArcObjects and invert a selection.

```vb
Public Sub InvertSelection()
     ' Get map document
    Dim pMXDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMXDoc = ThisDocument

    ' Get Map
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXDoc.FocusMap

    ' Get first layer and cast into FeatureLayer
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Set pFeatureLayer = pLayer

    ' Get selection on this layer
    Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
    Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer
    Dim pSelectionSet_Selected As ISelectionSet2
    Set pSelectionSet_Selected = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet

    ' Create a "selectionset" of all rows in the layer
    Dim pSelectionSet_All  As ISelectionSet2
    Set pSelectionSet_All = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.Select(Nothing, esriSelectionTypeIDSet, esriSelectionOptionNormal, Nothing)

    ' Create the inverted selection
    Dim pSelectionSet_Inverted As ISelectionSet2
    pSelectionSet_All.Combine pSelectionSet_Selected, esriSetDifference, pSelectionSet_Inverted

    ' Referesh layer with inverted selection and update map
    Set pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet = pSelectionSet_Inverted
    pMXDoc.ActivatedView.Refresh
End Sub
```